# how to make simulator look like Iphone?

Tags: iphone

Im not getting an option of iphone in Hardware-> devices. 
Show only iphone retina 3.5 and 4. 
I even pasted frame.png in iOS simulator folder but still the lay out is not displaying like  iphone frame. Displaying same IOS simulator lay out

Comment: Which iPhone do you mean, 5?

Comment: He wants the iPhone-like frame around the simulator that used to appear in the simulator when simulating older iPhones.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681352/ios-simulator-v5-1-window-is-missing-device-frame-and-home-button

Comment: Why is this important?  Is it just a "get a better feel for it" type thing? I admit it felt weird to not have that border anymore, but that's just the way the simulator works now.  If you run a retina simulator at 100% it takes up a great deal of screen real estate on a 27"Cinema Display.  That extra border for the frame wouldn't serve any additional functional purpose.

Comment: thank you guys for your comments here regarding my question. Actually im working as Intern-iOS Developer and my TL gave me a task to make this simulator look like iPhone, some how i managed to make it small and all icons now appearing on the screen of simulator but the main problem is that im not getting an option in the hardware-> devices->iPhone. there are only five options to select and those are: iPhone 3.5 retina, iPhone 4 retina, iPhone 4 for 64 bit iPad, ipad retina and one more but there is no any option related to iphone.

Comment: Ok Rob, so this option is only available in iOS 6.x?? im using Xcode 5.0.2 for application development.

Comment: Thank you Rob, but please tell me where im going to find project's settings?

Comment: Rob thank you so much for your help but still the layout of simulator is still same, not displaying like iPhone.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to know that which version of IOS simulator im using?

Answer (score 0):

If your app can run on iOS 6.1, in Xcode 5.0.2 you can go to your project settings and specify the iOS deployment target of 6.1, for example, and you'll have an option for a "iPhone" simulator which will be the 3.5" non-retina simulator that will feature the skin of the iPhone 4.

[image: deployment target]

Note, the skin of the iPhone will only show up if the simulator's "Window" menu has specified a scale of "100%".

Clearly, when you run your app on this 6.1 simulator, it will only function properly if your app is not dependent upon at iOS 7.0+ API.

Answer (score 0):

IT depend on your LCD/LED Display size