# How to use a custom iPhone simulator frame

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am attempting to add a custom iPhone simulator frame to use when running applications with the iOS Simulator. Particularly, I am trying to use a custom iPhone 5 frame for use with Xcode 5.1.

I found a [white iPhone 4 simulator frame](http://dribbble.com/shots/73904-White-iPhone-Simulator) on Dribbble which says that the frame can be used by navigating to the iOS simulator directory: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications`, right clicking on the iOS Simulator application, selecting "show package contents" and then navigating to Contents and then Resources. The name of the downloaded white iPhone 4 simulator frame referenced above is frame.png and the download also includes an additional image named homePressed.png.

However, within the Resources directory, I cannot find the default simulator frames that are used. Where would these default simulator frames be located? I am guessing that the default frame is also named frame.png and I am supposed to override that. Just adding the white iPhone 4 simulator frame to the Resources directory does not change the default frame that is being used. Perhaps this method of overriding the simulator frame no longer applies in the latest version of Xcode. Is there a way to override the default simulator frames in Xcode 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

After you click on "Show Package Contents" on the iOS simulator, drop the frame.png file into the ./Contents/Resources folder inside.  Voila!  Pretty simulator.

NOTE:  You MUST be using the full resolution of the iOS simulator (ie, on a Retina Display) to see the frame.  See answer here for more information:  [iOS Simulator v5.1 window is missing device frame and Home Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681352/ios-simulator-v5-1-window-is-missing-device-frame-and-home-button)

Comment: Unfortunately, adding frame.png into the ./Contents/Resources folder does not end up having it be used by the simulator. Does the frame.png file need to be a certain size in order for it to be used? I am using the iOS simulator version 7.1. Shouldn't I find the default frame.png inside ./Contents/Resources initially? I cannot find the original frame.png to overwrite.