# iOS Simulator not showing Home button

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios8

There are several questions that will resemble to this one but their solution is not quite what I'm looking for.

I have a Retina MBP (1920 x 1200), and previously I was able to run iOS Simulator 7 and simulate different devices (retina or not) and for all of them I was able to see the Home button. Now, with iOS simulator 8, I can no longer see the Home button. I don't want the Command-H functionality, I want to see the button because what I'm looking for is the orientation of the device (left, right, bottom or top). Without the Home button being visible, I cannot tell truly what orientation the device has.
I thought my Retina Mac was enough for the Home button to be displayed but I guess is something else.

Is there a way to show the Home button? or is something that my Retina MBP can no longer display.

p.s. Please, don't answer with "Why do you need/want to see the Home button?" if you don't have a solution for the question I'm asking.

Comment: If the display of the Home button is important to you, I suggest you file a bug report with Apple. You have a good use case (i.e. the need to see the device orientation unambiguously).

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It's definitely an issue that's not resolved by suggestions for older versions of iOS Simulator, e.g. cmd+1.

Comment: shortcut for home button is cmd + shift + h

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Retina Display macbook, you must set set the display to the highest resolution to see the iPad/iPad Retina frame on the simulator.

This answer from: [iOS Simulator v5.1 window is missing device frame and Home Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681352/ios-simulator-v5-1-window-is-missing-device-frame-and-home-button)

Comment: I knew this was an issue in previous versions and ever since I've set it to its max resolution and it worked for those previous versions but not for this new one. I'll file a bug with Apple and see what they have to say about it. Once I hear from them (if at all!), I'll be back and comment.